# Stanford NLP chunking for nested grammar

Tags: nltk, stanford-nlp, chunking

I made a switch from nltk to stanford-nlp and am finding trouble getting chunk results. A simple nested chunk grammar like

```
JJI:{(<JJ.*|VB.*>*)}
JJJ:{<RB.*>*(<TO>)?<JJI>?}
```

works like a charm in NLTK with easy code

```
cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar) 
result = cp.parse(sentence)
```

whereas its overly complicated in Stanford-NLP

TokenSequencePattern.getMultiPatternMatcher failed to give results for nested grammer

I turned to CoreMapExpressionExtractor.createExtractorFromFiles which required extensive configurations with ENV.defaults["stage"] and action: result: properties and intensive debugging. After much struggle I turned here to SO.

Is there no simpler way/api in Stanford-NLP like nltk.RegexpParser to perform such an elementary task?

Also if CoreMapExpressionExtractor.createExtractorFromFiles is the only way forward could someone please advice me on how the NERRulesFile.rules files should look like for this usecase?

Comment: Have you found any answers for that problem? I'm facing the same issue as you